# Python ORMs with attribute constraints such as required / optional?

Tags: python, django, orm, sqlalchemy, peewee

Here's what Pony ORM can do:

```
class Business(db.Entity):
    name        = Required(str)
    latitude    = Optional(float, py_check=lambda val: -90 <= val <= 90)
    longitude   = Optional(float, py_check=lambda val: -180 <= val <= 180)
```

I'm trying to determine if any of the others (SQLAlchemy, SQLObject, etc.) can do this. And especially, those that can be used as a library in a framework. (So, I'm not sure how much work it'd be to use the Django ORM in a non-Django app.)

I'm having a hard time finding this feature in the various docs, but I'm sure they support it.

**So my question:** Do these (or other) ORMs support required vs. optional attributes and validations? If so, how?

- SQLAlchemy
- SQLObject
- Storm
- Django
- Peewee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**SQLAlchemy**](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/): **Yes**

- Required/Optional is done by setting `nullable = False/True`
- Validations are done using [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators)

The code below uses [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), but pure sqlalchemy code is almost the same:

```
class Business(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'business'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)

    @db.validates('latitude')
    def validate_lat(self, key, value):
        assert value is None or (-90 <= value <= 90)
        return value

    @db.validates('longitude')
    def validate_lon(self, key, value):
        assert value is None or (-180 <= value <= 180)
        return value
```

---

As already noted by @kevin-christopher-henry, there is little point using Django ORM with non-Django framework, as well as the other way around: if you use Django, it is much *easier* to stick to Django ORM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not sure you'd want to use the Djano ORM in a non-Django app, but for the record this is how you'd do it using the built-in features of Django:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True,
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(-90), MaxValueValidator(90)])
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True,
                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(-180), MaxValueValidator(180)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Peewee does not support validators as part of the ORM, however you can use `Field.null` to indicate whether a field is required to have a value or not.